# Select * from Database 1 and insert into database 2

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

I have 2 Database in my VB.net application. I am using 1st database for daily operations. I would like to send one of the table records to online database. How Can I do that? First database is MSSQL Online database is MYSQL. I have created connections already using MYSQL .net connector.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304076/select-from-msql-and-insert-into-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [using a Linked Server instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) on SQL Server to write the data to MySQL using the four name notation.

[SQL SERVER – Explanation and Example Four Part Name](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/26/sql-server-explanation-and-example-four-part-name/)

[SQL Server Four-part naming](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1095)

Comment: 4 part naming wont work.  He is using MSSQL on one server and MySQL on another.

Comment: @Kaius: You're unfamiliar with SQL Server's Linked Server functionality.  The OP states that SQL Server is the main, and MySQL is the online backup.

Comment: Cursing 2005 Full Text thesaurus & noise words, currently :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a rough set of steps you need to follow

1. Query the MSSQL database and retrieve the data you want. Storing it in a DataTable may be the best option starting off.
2. Loop through the DataTable rows and build an INSERT statement that will be run against the MYSQL database.
3. Execute the command against the MYSQL db.

This is the basics of what you need to do to get a simple working system.  Also take a look at Transactions as a way to manage the rollback of data when something goes wrong.

**I'm assuming this is a research project**  If you are planning on using this code in a production system then i would look into a different alternative such as uploading data files to a service attached to the MYSQL database.  This would allow you to batch and retry an import when something goes wrong.